# In angular js is there any way so that i could assign app.comment==null if point is not 1 through front end logic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

`if(app.point !=1) app.comment==null`-is it possible to check through front end in angular Js

```
<td>
    <input 
         type="number"
         max="5"
         min="1"
         ng-init="app.point=5"
         data-ng-model="app.point">
</td>
<td>
    <textarea 
        data-ng-disabled="app.point==1 ? false:true"
        data-ng-model="app.comment" 
        ng-init="app.comment=null" 
        style="resize:none;height:40px;width:200px">
    </textarea>
</td>
<!-- data-ng-bind=" app.point !=1 ? app.comment==null:app.comment" -->
```

Comment: Where are you setting app.point value from? In init its 5, and where it will be updated to someother value? Are you looking to set app.comment as null or compare it will null if app.point != 1

Comment: What exactly you want to do..? explain..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The best way to add a **watcher** on this variable.

```
$scope.$watch('app.point', function (oldval,newval) {
        if(newval != 1)
        {
            app.comment==null
        }
    });
```

Add this code in your controller. Whenever the value of this variable changes, it will perform this mentioned task.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input type="number" max="5" min="1" data-ng-model="app.point" ng-change="someFunction(app.point)"></td>
<td><textarea
   data-ng-model="app.comment"
   style="resize:none;height:40px;width:200px">
   </textarea> 
</td>
In Controller:
$scope.app.point= function(appComment){
   if(appComment!=1)
       //put condition
   else
       //put another condition
}
```

Comment: it is list of items and  if client changes the point value in front end app.commet status will be change based on app.point

Comment: data-ng-bind=" app.point !=1 ? app.comment==null:app.comment"
this works but in i can not put more than one character in the textarea field in a single time

Comment: So you mean if he selects 1 in input, then he should be able to type only one character in textare..?

Comment: Dude the code I have put is doing same. It is tracking the number app.point and on every change in number it is picking the number and sending to that function.now with if condition you can do anything According to your requirement..